# Invalid syntax из ничего

Tags: python

Код скопирован один в один из источника, только в источнике код работает.
![Собственно вывод консоли][image]

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import os
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Handle(FyleSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_track):
            extension = filename.split(".")
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == "mp3"):
                file = folder_track + "/" + filename
                new_path = folder_dest + "/" + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

folder_track = '/Users/Anton/Downloads'
folder_dest = '/users/Anton/Desktop/Music'

handle = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(handle, folder_track, recursive=True)
observr.start()

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Простите, но.... А где, собственно ошибка Invalid syntax??? В стеке ее нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимум три описки, не знаю как вы копировали:

```
class Handle(FyleSystemEventHandler): -> class Handle(FileSystemEventHandler):
              ^                                        ^

handle = Handler() -> handle = FileSystemEventHandler()
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

observr.start() -> observer.start()
                         ^
```

Comment: Но к invalid syntax это всё-таки не имеет отношения

Comment: После этих трех исправлений у меня только на отсутствие файла стало ругаться

Comment: Но и до этих исправлений у вас ругалось вовсе не на invalid syntax :) Автор вопроса явно что-то не договаривает

Comment: А, ну я что нашел то зарепортил. В голову к автору лезть я не нанимался )